# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert/select ids for bulk delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, bulk, createquery

There are the following java-code:

```
EntityTransaction myTransaction = myManager.getTransaction();
myTransaction.begin();
System.out.println(myManager.createQuery("delete from UserProfile where id > 16787504").executeUpdate());
myTransaction.commit();
```

After run, the error occurs:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert/select ids for bulk delete
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:60)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you seen the generated SQL ?

Comment: Have you tried adding an alias for the object? Try the following "DELETE FROM UserProfile up WHERE up.id > 16787504"